# Am I doing multi threading the right way in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that runs multiple threads to convert pdf files to images in a folder and its subdirectories. It iterates through that folder, putting all pdf file names in a list, and then use that list to divide up the work between 4 threads that i created. Now it all works perfectly. Multiple threads are running and converting pdf files at the same time to different locations i specify.

I would just like to know if im doing it in the right way. Almost every website i visit do multi threading in a different way, and i don't know which one would be the most effective and ultimately the right one.

No good doing some thing that works, if its done wrong i guess... Just going to get me in the future.

I would love if you could just look at the code here and see if there is anything Drastically wrong that i need to change regarding multiple threads running

```
static object LockInteger = new object();
static object LockIfCheck = new object();
static object LockInteger = new object();
static object LockIfCheck = new object();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IterateThrough(txtboxdirectory.Text);
}

public void IterateThrough(string sourceDir)
{
    MulThread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        int lowerbound = 0;
        int upperbound = (fileList.Count / 4);
        for (int i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
        {
            forFunction(exceptionFileList, fileList[i], compltetedFileList,sourceDir, dir1);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            lblFileExecutionTime.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => lblFileExecutionTime.Text = "Execution Per File " + stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString())));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
    });
    MulThread.Start();

    MulThread1 = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        int lowerbound = fileList.Count / 4;
        int upperbound = (fileList.Count / 4) * 2;
        for (int i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
        {
            forFunction(exceptionFileList, fileList[i], compltetedFileList, sourceDir, dir2);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            lblFileExecutionTime.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => lblFileExecutionTime.Text = "Execution Per File " + stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString())));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
    });
    MulThread1.Start();

    MulThread2 = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        int lowerbound = (fileList.Count / 4) * 2;
        int upperbound = (fileList.Count / 4) * 3;
        for (int i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
        {
            forFunction(exceptionFileList, fileList[i], compltetedFileList, sourceDir, dir3);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            lblFileExecutionTime.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => lblFileExecutionTime.Text = "Execution Per File " + stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString())));
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
    });
    MulThread2.Start();

    MulThread3 = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        int lowerbound = (fileList.Count / 4) * 3;
        int upperbound;

        if (fileList.Count % 4 != 0)
        {
            upperbound = ((fileList.Count / 4) * 4) + (fileList.Count % 4) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            upperbound = ((fileList.Count / 4) * 4) + (fileList.Count % 4);
        }

        for (int i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
        {
            forFunction(exceptionFileList, fileList[i], compltetedFileList, sourceDir, dir4);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            lblFileExecutionTime.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => lblFileExecutionTime.Text = "Execution Per File " + stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString())));

            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
        }
    });
    MulThread3.Start();
}
```

Then i lock some of the methods in "forFunction".

```
private int forFunction(String exceptionFileList, FileInfo z, String compltetedFileList, String sourceDir, String imagedirectory)
{
    //heres where it locked up because of this global variable
    lock (LockInteger)
    {
        atPDFNumber++;
    }

    int blankImage = 1;
    int pagesMissing = 0;

    //delete the images currently in the folder
    deleteCreatedImages(imagedirectory);

    //Get the amount of pages in the pdf
    int numberPDFPage = numberOfPagesPDF(z.FullName);

    //Convert the pdf to images on the users pc
    convertToImage(z.FullName, imagedirectory);

    //Check the images for blank pages
    blankImage = testPixels(imagedirectory, z.FullName);

    //Check if the conversion couldnt convert a page because of an error
    pagesMissing = numberPDFPage - numberOfFiles;

    //int pagesMissing = 0;

    //Cancel button is pressed
    if (toContinue == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    lock (LockIfCheck)
    {
        //If there is a blank page, or if there is a missing page
        if (blankImage == 0 || pagesMissing > 0)
        {
            myholder = 1;
            exceptionFileList += "File Name: " + z.Name + "\r\n"
           + "File Path: " + z.FullName + "\r\n \r\n";

            String currentValue = exceptionFileList;
            txtboxProblemFiles.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => txtboxProblemFiles.Text += currentValue.ToString())));

            String currentValue3 = z.FullName;
            txtboxProblemFiles.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => listboxProblemFiles.Items.Add(currentValue3))));
        }
        else
        {
            compltetedFileList += "Scanning Completed of file: " + "\r\n"
            + "File Name: " + z.Name + "\r\n"
           + "File Path: " + sourceDir + "\r\n \r\n";
        }

        String currentValue1 = "File Name: " + z.Name + "\r\n";
        txtboxCheckedFiles.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => txtboxCheckedFiles.Text += currentValue1)));
    }


    myWorkerClass();        

    return 1;
}
```

I'll accept any up building criticism from this code.

Comment: Your question might be a better fit at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you. Never even knew that site existed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested way for multitrheading is by using [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

The benefit of ThreadPool is that it manages thread creation, job assignment ,... and gives you better performance alongside less resource usage.

A sample of ThreadPool from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class Example {
    public static void Main() {

        // Queue the task.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    // This thread procedure performs the task. 
    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo) {

        // No state object was passed to QueueUserWorkItem, so  
        // stateInfo is null.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from the thread pool.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah Alright. Thus if you would want to make more than one thread one would declare them in the thread pool?

Comment: Of course, you can do it manually just like what you did already, but the preferred way is to let CLR handle your required threads via ThreadPool. Both of them work.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, will try that now and see how much performance will increase. And even if it doesnt increase, its then more the right way of doing it.

Comment: Your welcome. I'll enjoy when someone else use Multi Threading. Idk ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is that depends. Are you starting threads, yes. Does it look like you are protecting shared data yes. It does look like you have copy-pasted code everywhere. That could be abstracted into a function and the upper and lower bounds made into arguments. I think you might be able to reduce this and use the Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach. Lastly, I can't quite remember the multithreading issue that relates to GUI. I see that you are using some GUI here. But you need to make sure that the change to the labels are made by the GUI thread and not some other thread.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the changes made to the UI by threads other than the GUI thread did cause a problem, thats why if i want to change something i have to do that whole BeginInvoke(action) besides the setText of a label or whatever.
Never used Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach Before, will have to read up about hat.